# How is screen rotation achieved in terms of battery life?

Tags: android, accelerometer

Hi I am working on an Android app which should detect user movements with accelerometer and according to it run some further actions. I have a service which listens to sensormanager updates but, there is a problem, the accelerometer drains the battery pretty fast:-\ 
Please is it possible to save the battery for example with lower sampling rate of the sensor? 
How does it the operating system with screen rotation? There must be sensor running all the time, isn't it true? 
Thank you for your help, I hope you will understand my question. In case of not, I can post some further info..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `SensorManager` class provides different registering methods, and [some of them](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#registerListener%28android.hardware.SensorEventListener,%20android.hardware.Sensor,%20int%29) have a delay parameter. The higher the delay, the less battery it drains:

```
  public boolean registerListener (SensorEventListener listener, Sensor sensor, int rate)
```

The Android developers guide has a section on the matter. I recommend you to read it, in particular the [best practices](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html#sensors-practices) section.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to consider that android has to detect movement only with screen on..
When you will register for accelerometer updates it will keep the device awake,which will have impact on the battery life..
That's why there are coming things like HW sensor events batching (came with KitKat) which basically outsources this to a single purpose low energy chip ( hence it only works on  supported chips like snapdragon 800) and does not hold the device awake all the time..you can find more about this in the official documentation...